# Is Japanese "subaru" related to Russian "soberu" and Latin "conferre"?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, japanese

Is Japanese "subaru" related to Russian "soberu" ("I'll put together") and Latin "conferre" ("to bring together")?

I think both Latin and Russian words derive from Proto-Indo-European "***com bheroa̯***" "I am putting together".

Answer (score 3):

No relation at all. In linguistics the absence of a genetic relation is the null hypothesis. The burden of proof relies on those who claim a certain etymological relation or a common origin of two or more words. So, unless someone proves the relation between *subaru* and the other two words, the answer is: unrelated.

P.S. Don't let phonetic similarities fool yourself: when two words sound alike this is a good hint of their unrelatedness. Genetically related words usually have different phonetic shapes, as you can witness for Russian *soberu* (first singular of *sobrat'* 'to collect', formed by the prefix *so*- and the root *ber*/*bir*/*br*, meaning 'to take' and going back to the PIE root **bher** 'bring') and Latin *conferre* (a prefixed verb with multiple meanings relating to the notion of 'bringing' and going back to the same PIE root as the aforementioned Russian verb).

Comment: Well, Starostin's database gives for Proto-Altaic "č`óme" "together" and "bi̯ṓr" for "take, collect", the both cognates to Proto-Indo-European at Eurasiatic level. But in modern Japanese these would result in "tomohiro" (interestingly, there is such name in Japanese!). Still, there is possibility it is a borrowing from another Altaic language.

Comment: @Anixx you cannot say "it is possibly a borrowing from another Altaic language" **as if** the Altaic connection were an established fact because, effectively, it is not. You've made a good attempt, you checked out on Starostin's database, and you answered to yourself that Japanese form does not fit with this etymology. Therefore, the answer to the original question is still "unrelated". (Not to speak about the fact that neither the Altaic family nor the Nostratic genetic connection are widely accepted facts in historical linguistics).

Comment: I still cannot find the etymology of "subaru" (it comes from "suberu" meaning "rule, superwise" but no further connection). And the meaning of the name "Tomohiro" seems to contradict Starostin (it means "wide wisdom")

Comment: by the way, *subaru* and *suberu* have *sub* as their root (not 100% sure, but almost). The remaining is a secondary suffix and can be disregarded, for our concern. This makes further enquiry meaningless, because there is nothing related to *sub* in either the Russian or the Latin form.

Comment: See the etymology of both Japanese words in this book (p. 112 and 144): https://books.google.it/books?id=7ysws67HZegC